# Finding numbers from Mean, Variance and Correlation coefficient

Tags: st.statistics

I have a set of numbers $A=\lbrace a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n \rbrace$

I want to find new numbers    $X=\lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n \rbrace$ such

1. [Mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PopulationMean.html)

$$\mu(A )=\mu(X)$$

2. [Variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html)

   $$Var(A)=Var(X)$$
3. [Correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)  $$r_{AX}=k $$

Where $k$ is a some constant, $0<k<1$ and each number $x_1(k),x_2(k)...x_n(k)$  depends only on $k$.

Comment: You might benefit from looking at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products

Comment: Can't be done -- the $x_m(k)$ have to depend on at least one of the $a_m$.  If each number  $x_m(k)$ is allowed to depend only on $k$ and $a_m$ then I think there is a solution.